# What would cause a compiler to fail randomly?

Tags: clang

I am using the clang compiler on windows. I used the installer from the LLVM website. Sometimes it gives me a compiler error.

`clang -I./include main.c CoreFoundation.dll`

it gives:

```
In file included from main.c:4:
In file included from ./include\CoreFoundation/CFNumberFormatter.h:110:
./include\CoreFoundation/CFXMLParser.h:159:81: error: unknown type name 'CFXMLNodeRef'
typedef void *          (*CFXMLParserCreateXMLStructureCallBack)(CFXMLParserRef parser, 

CFXMLNodeRef nodeDesc, void *info);
...
```

and sometimes this..

```
In file included from main.c:4:
In file included from ./include\CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h:86:
./include\CoreFoundation/CFDateFormatter.h:104:105: error: unknown type name 'CFDateRef'; did you mean 'CFDataRef'?
CFStringRef CFDateFormatterCreateStringWithDate(CFAllocatorRef allocator, CFDateFormatterRef formatter, CFDateRef date) AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3_AND_LATER;
...
```

...and other similar warnings, seemingly randomly choosing where to stop. Sometimes it compiles through without error. When it gives an error, they seem to be be about not finding a symbol from an included file. It doesn't complain about not finding the file. But it doesn't consistently stop at the same point and sometimes compiles successfully.

Comment: When you say "sometimes" do you mean you can make no changes to your source,the environment etc and just recompile, recompile, recompile and get different error messages each time?

Comment: @Poldie exactly. I'm guessing it's either a bug in the way the compiler was installed, or a bug in clang-more likely the first, but clang support on windows seems to be limited.

Comment: Can you provide your code? It is hard to say something about this problem when we cannot reproduce it. One possibility: faulty hardware as @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said.

Comment: Did you do a `make clean` and is the clean directive properly cleaning *all* intermediate files? I once had this happen to me because of a typo ("Obj" instead of "obj").

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this "error" under Linux with gcc. I even get the "report this compiler bug pls" message.

> When it gives an error, they seem to be be about not finding a symbol from an included file

You can get this:

1. if you compile with multiple threads (eg. make -j8)
2. if you abort the compile and then start it again without "cleaning" all obj files
3. if you compiled your source, changed something and compile without "cleaning"
4. if your compiler/make/build process changes the order every time... (had this with cmake and opencv 3 source)